# CSS selector exclude first child then fallow nth child pattern

Tags: css, sass

Not sure why this not working:

```
:not(first-child):nth-child(3n+2){
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right:30px;
}
```

It goes through the pattern 3n+2, I want to exclude from this pattern the first child, is this possible?

this works but that's 4 line of code. I would like to reduce the code of this snippet:

```
:nth-child(3n+2){
  margin-right:30px;
}
:nth-child(3n+4){
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Doesn't `nth-child(3n+2)` *already* exclude the first-child?

Comment: @Paulie_D inside this count it still includes first child `nth-child(3n+2)`, hows that excluding? i want to start counting this 'nth-child(3n+2)' from second child tahts why i tried putting `:not(first-child)`

Comment: I really not clear on what is is you are trying to do. That's why we need a demo of the issue.

Comment: @Paulie_D i dont think it needs an example ive put more stuff let me know if makes sense

Comment: You should add you HTML code as well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a colon (:) before first-child, so it should be -

```
:not(:first-child):nth-child(3n+2){
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right:30px;
}
```

Please refer the following code snippet.

```css
span {
  color: white;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: black;
}

span:not(:first-child):nth-child(3n+1) {
  background-color: red;
}

span:nth-child(3n+2) {
  background-color: blue;
}

span:nth-child(3n+3) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
  <span>6</span>
  <span>7</span>
  <span>8</span>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: could you post code snippet showing that it works for you as it doesnt for me

Comment: @user9013856 I have added a code snippet in my answer for your reference. Please observe that (3n+2)th child or (3n+3)th child can never be the first child, hence applying ":not(:first-child)" for both these cases will have no effect.

Answer (score -1):

check out this solution here I add CSS exclude the 1st one element you can follow this pattern. Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions do not support the: nth-child() selector.

```css
p:nth-child(1n+2) {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<p>The first.</p>
<p>The second.</p>
<p>The third.</p>
<p>The fourth .</p>
</body>
</html>
```